# Can't get response from Jsoup on sended form

Tags: android, forms, jsoup, response

i'm trying to send a form to a site and get the response in an Android application. Thing is, the response is just empty html file (just the tags html, head and body, open and closed), nothing more.
Here is my code:

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("http://m.correios.com.br/movel/calculaPrecos.do").method(Connection.Method.GET)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.0 Safari/537.36")
                        .execute();
                Document document = Jsoup
                        .connect("http://m.correios.com.br/movel/precos.do")
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.0 Safari/537.36")
                        .data("servico", "40215")
                        .data("cepOrigem", "97010-200")
                        .data("cepDestino", "97015-259")
                        .data("peso", "1")
                        .data("formato", "1")
                        .data("comprimento", "23")
                        .data("altura", "23")
                        .data("largura", "23")
                        .data("diametro", "")
                        .data("maoPropria", "N")
                        .data("valorDeclarado", "")
                        .data("avisoRecebimento", "N")
                        .data("metodo", "calcular")
                        .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                        .followRedirects(true)
                        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                        .post();
                System.out.println("Output>>> "+document.toString());
```

[the form which i got from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjbzv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong URL for the `POST` request. You are using `http://m.correios.com.br/movel/precos.do` but it should be `http://m.correios.com.br/movel/calculaPrecos.do` - same as for the `GET` request (notice the part before the last dot).

Comment: God, haven't seen it... Thanks!